# Crypto & Paramiko issue

Tags: python, paramiko, pycrypto

I've installed paramiko using command:

> sudo apt-get install python-paramiko

That installed pyCrypto too. Currently, when I try to import paramiko, i get following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/paramiko-1.7.7.1-py2.6.egg/paramiko/util.py", line 32, in   
from paramiko.common 
import * File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/paramiko-1.7.7.1-py2.6.egg/paramiko/common.py", line 98, in 
from Crypto import Random ImportError: cannot import name Random
```

When I copy Crypto files to directory with my python script I get following:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256 ImportError: cannot import name SHA256
```

Second error was even when I don't install paramiko, just copy crypto and paramiko files to my script directory.

There's no file SHA256.py in my directory, I don't know where can I get it.

Comment: You might want to revisit old questions and accept some of the answers in order to draw more help to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian/Ubuntu, avoid installing python-* packages with `apt-get`, unless the python package has tricky binary or OS dependencies. For paramiko, you can go without the apt package. Preferably, install inside a virtualenv.

```
$ virtualenv foo
$ . foo/bin/activate
(foo)$ pip install paramiko
(foo)$ python
>>> import paramiko
```

Works like a charm. You may need to install the virtualenv and pip commands using apt-get.

Comment: When I install it using pip I'm getting following error: http://dpaste.com/631952/. When I try to import paramiko, I'm getting error: no module named Crypto.

Comment: Gcc fails. Did you install the python header files (python-dev for apt)?

Answer (score 0):

For linux you can try with pip:
    `pip install paramiko`
Or you can download the paramiko module [from here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/2.3.1)